# Substring with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, substring

Well, I have investigated but nothin seems to work D:

I have this

```
    Create Table Client
    (
        Name varchar(15),
        Last_Name varchar(30)
    )

    insert into Client values ('Ralph', 'Van Beethoven')

    Create Table Client_Det
    (
       First_Last_Name varchar(15),
       Second Last Name varchar(15)
    )
```

What I need is to separte the Last Name 'Van Beethoven' from Client and insert it into Client_Det something like this:

```
First Last Name: Van

Second Last Name: Beethoven
```

What can I do?

Comment: What about surnames like "van der Waal"? Although there can be spaces in surnames, they are not separate parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
insert into Client_Det
select
    case charindex(' ', Last_Name) when 0 then Last_Name else left(Last_Name,charindex(' ', Last_Name)-1) end as First_Last_Name
,   case charindex(' ', Last_Name) when 0 then null else right(Last_Name,len(Last_Name)-charindex(' ', Last_Name)) end as Second_Last_Name
from client
```

The idea is to use [`charindex(' ', Last_Name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to detect spaces in the `Last_Name` column. If there is no space, use the entire column for `First_Last_Name`, and put a `NULL` into `Second_Last_Name`. Otherwise, split at the space, and put the two parts into separate columns.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ef70/1)